# Stochastic dominance of linearly and quadratically weighted distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose $X\ge 0$ is a continuous random variable with density function $f(x)$.
For $i=1,2$, let $X_i$ be the random variable with density function proportional to $x^i f(x)$.

**Question**: Is it true that $X_2$ (first-order) stochastically dominates $X_1$?

I know $E[X_2]\ge E[X_1]$ follows from Cauchy Schwartz inequality:
$$E[X_2] = \frac{\int_0^\infty x^3 f(x)dx }{\int_0^\infty x^2 f(x)dx } \ge \frac{\int_0^\infty x^2 f(x)dx }{\int_0^\infty x f(x)dx } = E[X_1].$$

I also know this is true if $X$ is an exponential random variable. The dominance follows from the density function of Gamma distributions. But I don't know how to start for the general case.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The quotient of the density functions is proportional to $x$, which is increasing. Thus $X_1$ is smaller than $X_2$ is the likelihood ratio order. Hence also smaller in the first stochastic order.